# Proving $x^4+2$ cannot be factored into $2$ degree polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

My book says that it can't be because if I try to write $x⁴+10x³+15x²+5x+12$

as:

$$x^4+2$$

(which is $p(x) mod 5$)

then $x⁴+2$ is irreducible because:

$$x^4+2 = (ax²+bx+c)(a'x²+b'x+c)$$

is impossible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

I used $a=1$ and [did](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%2Bb*x%2Bc%29%28x%5E2%2Bd*x%2Be%29):

(x²+bx+c)(x²+dx+e)

which is equal to

$$x^4 + (b+d)x³+(bd+c+e)x²+(eb+cd)x+ec$$

then I tried to solve [this system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b%2Bd%3D0%3Bb*d%2Bc%2Be%3D0%3Be*b%2Bc*d%3D0%3B%20e*c%3D1) but as you can see, it's incomplete.

How do I prove that I can't solve this system over $\mathbb{Z}_5?$

Comment: Another way: The element $-2=3$ is of order four in $\Bbb{F}_5$. Therefore the zeros of your polynomial are of order sixteen (in some extension field of $\Bbb{F}_5$). So theorder of the multiplicative group of that extension field, $5^m-1$, has to be a multiple of sixteen (Lagrange). But the smallest positive $m$ such that $16\mid 5^m-1$ is $m=4$. Therefore the minimal polynomial has degree $m=4$ as well, and thus your polynomial has to be irreducible.

Comment: It's also 2-Eisenstein (are you working over $\mathbb{Q}?$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing coefficients of several $x^n$, you can get that

- $b = -d$ (look at $x^3$) and they are both non-zero, because otherwise $e = -c$ (look at $x^2$) and $-e^2 = 2$ which is impossible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$
- Assuming $ b = -d \not= 0$, you get that $e=c$ (by looking at the degree 1 coefficient) so $e^2 = 2$ which is also impossible.

So all cases are settled, and this polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

It could be useful to note that $2$ is not a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{F}_5$. It follows that the equation $x^2 - 2 = 0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{F}_5$. Therefore, your polynomial can't be factored as $(x - a)P(x)$. Afterwards, you have to check if it can be factored as two monic irreducible polynomials.

Comment: My fault. I made a big mistake. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: If a monic polynomial factors, it can factor into monic polynomials (you did this already).

Step 2: Either the degree 4 polynomial has a root (which this one doesn't), or it has two *irreducible* degree-2 monic factors.

Step 3: List all the irreducible quadratic monic polynomials mod 5.  They are:
$$x^2+2, x^2+3, x^2+x+1, x^2+x+2, x^2+2x+3, x^2+2x+4, x^2+3x+3, x^2+3x+4, x^2+4x+1, x^2+4x+2$$

Note: There are $10=\frac{5\cdot 4}{2}$ of them; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/556237/73324).

Step 4: Check that no two of them multiply to $x^4+2$.  There are not that many cases to check, as the constant coefficients must multiply to $2$ (mod 5).  Hence they must be $\{1,2\}$ or $\{3,4\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Comparing degree $3$ coefficients gives $d = -b$. Then, comparing degree $1$ coefficients gives $d(c - e) = 0$.

> We cannot have $c = e$, because comparing degree $0$ coefficients would give $c^2 = 2$, but $2$ is not a square in $\Bbb Z_5$. Hence $d(c - e) = 0$ implies $b = d = 0$. This leaves $x^4 + (c + e) x^2 + c e = x^4 + 2$. Now, $e = -c$, so $-c^2 = 2$ and hence $c^2 = -2$, but $-2$ is not a square in $\Bbb Z_5$ either, so there are no such factorizations.

Answer (score 0):

$x^4+2$ can be factored into  2  degree polynomials (If you do not say explicitly with rational coefficients, then it can be factored in such a way); indeed

$$x^4+2=(x^2+\sqrt[4]8x+\sqrt 2)(x^2-\sqrt[4]8x+\sqrt 2)$$

Answer (score 0):

An other solution would look like this:

Suppose $x^4+2 = (ax^2+bx+c) \cdot (\bar a x^2 + \bar b x + \bar c)$ in $\mathbb{F_5}$,

then,

$c \cdot \bar c = 2 $ and $a \cdot \bar a = 1$

$\implies  (c,\bar c) \in \{  (1,2), (3,4) \}$

and

$\implies (a, \bar a) \in \{ (1,1), (2,3), (4,4)\}$

$\implies a \cdot \bar c + \bar a \cdot c \in \{ 2, 3\} $

$\implies \bar (c \cdot a + c \cdot \bar a )x^2 \neq 0 $